# Styling Elements

Tags: html, css

How do I position certain elements, like headings, horizontal rows, etc so they are in the position I want them to be. It's quite difficult to explain, but here's an example so you can understand.

I have my basic logo placed in the top left (it's a template logo for now) on the same line, or same "position" I need it to be placed directly opposite the logo on the other side of the page. Only problem is that it appears below my logo.

Here's an example of how I expect it to be:
https://gyazo.com/b904252fa22783b78e820d57318798cc

This is how it really is:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/seesqz9u/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css">
  <title>CSGOMarble</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="logo">
  <img src="logo.png" alt="LOGO" height="60px" width="200px">
</div>
<a href="http://www.steamcommunity.com/login/">
<h3 style="float: right; position: fixed;">SIGN IN WITH STEAM</h3>
</a>
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="coinflip.html">COINFLIP</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
background-color: white;
}
.logo {
margin-left: 25px;
}
.navbar {
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 25px;
padding: 0;
font-size: 25px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
li {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}

li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content which uses `float: right;` should appear **before** left content in the HTML.

In other words, move your `<h3>` tag above the div containing the logo, and remove the `position` property, it's not necessary.

You should also change the order of the tags -- `<h3><a>` rather than `<a><h3>`

```
  <body>  
    <h3 style="float: right;"><a href="http://www.steamcommunity.com/login/">SIGN IN WITH STEAM</a></h3>

    <div class="logo">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="LOGO" height="60px" width="200px">
    </div>

    <hr>
```

**[updated filddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/seesqz9u/1/)**

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

You have put the logo in a div element.
The div element will take the complete row and will not allow any other element to come beside it. (in css terms it is a block element)

Either keep the logo in span element orelse add css in your logo div and make it display as inline-block

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: My logo is in a div element.

Comment: make it span or add the css to div as suggested in answer

Comment: Also i see that you are using h3 tag for sign in. h3 is also a block element. It will take complete row element and will not allow any other element to come beside it(for your case logo) so change the style of h3 to display: inline-block